# How to ellipsize center-aligned textview beside a right-aligned button when screen width is small

Tags: android, android-layout

```
 ------------------------------------
|           LONG_TITL...   |button|  |
|------------------------------------|
|                                    |
```

I have an app header which consists of the app title and a button. The button should be fixed on the right side but I want the title to be in the middle and ellipsize when the screen is too small. Problem is the title just won't ellipsize even though the button is nearly beside it.

Here's what I have so far:

```xml
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/headr"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bar_orange"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:minHeight="40dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/bar_orange"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Title"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/bcd"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <Button
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:background="@drawable/button_home"
        android:text="@string/home"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Is there a way to do this with just `RelativeLayout`?

Comment: how about android:ellipsize="end"

Comment: I've tried that too and other possible values but it doesn't work. I tried increasing the button's left margin but the title won't budge..

Comment: check the answer below

Answer (score 1):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="very large center align text very large center align text very large center align text" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="Right button" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: the problem with this is that the title is not in the center.

Comment: if there is no view on the left of the title, it will take as much as space needed though its centered.if still unable to show some text, then it will apply ellipsize propery.If you want to get your title exactly on the center regardless of other views then you have to use weight for the all views where title resides.

Comment: Hmm.. but if I have to use weights, then I should not use `LinearLayout`, right? Or is better if I just add an invisible view in the left?

Comment: you better use LinearLayout

Comment: err yeah. sorry, it should be "..then I should use `LinearLayout`..."

Answer (score 1):

add this to your textView

```
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
  android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to `android:ellipsize="end"` in TextView.

Answer (score 0):

Set a fixed width for the TextView